# Not able to access Azure SQL Server - Login failed

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am not able to connect to Azure sql server from my machine, I have added my public IP and azure sql server is configured for remote access but I am getting error

> Cannot connect to your Azure SQL DB logical server/Azure SQL MI server, exception: Cannot open server "SERVER NAME" requested
>   by the login.  The login failed.

Note: I am able to connect to Azure SQL database from Azure portal.

Comment: How are you connecting? With username and password or Azure AD login?

Comment: Understanding how you are trying to connect will help. Things like MFA can play a part. Can you add to your question

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case, you should try to download Azure Data Studio and log in with your Microsoft account that you used for Azure.

May I ask you to add in a screenshot of your login detail (you can just fake the login but the syntax must be the same) so that the community is able to understand the situation better :D